# Is it possible to create an Android spinner components 'ArrayAdapter' with out using the xml layout reference?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my Android application I create the layout programatically (ie an xml layout file not used for creating the component layout), in this case how can I create a spinner component programatically? Especially the setAdapter portion of spinner component, Is it possible create an ArrayAdapter with out using an XML layout reference like 'android.R.layout.spinner_item'?

```
          Spinner sp_gender = new Spinner(this);
          ArrayList<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>(); 

         ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
               android.R.layout.spinner_item, new String[] {   
                      "Male", 
                      "Female"                
                     });

         sp_gender.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter); 

         ll_main.addView(sp_gender);
```

In the above code I want to remove the xml file reference portion 'android.R.layout.spinner_item' because I create the layout  completely in the activity class.

Comment: post your code what you have tried?

Comment: ArrayList<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();
       
       Spinner sp_gender = new Spinner(this);

       
       ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
             android.R.layout.spinner_item, new String[] {   
                    "Male", 
                    "Female"                
                   });

     
       sp_gender.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter); 
       
       ll_main.addView(sp_gender);  in the above code the I want to remove the xml layout reference porion 'android.R.layout.spinner_item'

Comment: You should add your code in the question itself not in comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***No its not possible***. Because ArrayAdapter has no default constructor. also u need to specify the structure of the view and also on which it should draw the view thats why arrayadapter takes layout id and context as one of its parameter

`ArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId)` is the  constructor of ArrayAdapter with least parameter.